# Getting http acces from my own server IP

Tags: apache-2.4, openvpn

i want to ask regarding something seems weird..

i use mod_security to protect the websites
recently when i checked my httpd server access log, i'm seeing my server ip is accessing the website on its own. not only that, my server ip also attempt to access non existing folder like phpmyadmin and attempt to hack itself.

i also added antispam for my registration page and log every ip that marked as spam.
When i checked the antispam log, my server ip was on the list.
how does this happen, does someone gets to use my server ip and attempt to register on my website?

i also have openvpn service running that use port-share 443, however this vpn are use only by me and some friends. does this any can be related to the issue?

*i believe the server is well protected for now, no one gets to access yet. its just weird how does someone gets to use the server ip.

## ============
***Updates

After some checking, i remembered that i use port-share for openvpn using port 443. Due to this i think the client are redirected through openvpn to my webserver and causing my PHP to detect its own IP address.

For php code to detect the client IP, is uses $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
i also tried other combination from here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699101/get-the-client-ip-address-using-php
but it won't show any IP.

Can someone help me to fix this to display the correct IP of client while using port-share with openvpn? is it achieavable or not?

Thank you.

Comment: What did you install on the server?

Comment: only just a few services, 
OpenVPN, dnsmasq, apache. i also use key to login to the server.

Comment: Hi sir @MichaelHampton, if you could check on my new founding, could you be of any help? Thanks..